# Move a Range in ClosedXML

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, closedxml

I have gone all through their Wiki and cannot find an option to move a range or even to paste a range.  I see copy but no paste.  I know I can use .Value = .Value but that will not work in my case.

I have Columns like this:

BDM | EQ_CODE | PC_CODE | PRODUCT | CAT_DESC | BUYER | DEPT | SMANAGER

and I need to move them like this:

PRODUCT | CAT_DESC | DEPT | EQ_CODE | PC_CODE | BDM | BUYER | SMANAGER

and I cannot just insert a bunch of columns in the front and then do one column at a time because that will mess a lot of ranges that I have set up on the worksheet. I need to move them in place.  what is the easiest way to do this with closedxml? or am I better off using interop with this?

Comment: Can you just change the range address?

Comment: @Programnik what do you mean can I just change the Range Address?

Comment: ranges have an address, or if its a column a column.  If this is not read only, try just changing the column of the range.  This might make all other columns shuffle along and preserve relative formulas.

Comment: No, range addresses as immutable and can't be changed.